# Symphony Objects and Excel Application Objects Help File in Lotus Notes

Tags: excel, lotus-notes, lotusscript

Does the Symphony Objects and Excel Application Object have help.nsf? I am trying to learn and understand exporting and importing symphony and Excel files through Lotus scripts but I am having a hard time since I can't find any help for it and even on the net there are a lot of examples but I want to learn it more step by step and the specific action or method for each object.

I tried doing the reference part of the link below where I can see all the list of actions or methods of symphony object but I can't find it.

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/lotus/library/symphony-toolkit/

If there is no help file for them do you know any sites that really explains on using those objects clearly just like how helps work?

Lastly, Excel must be installed for the Excel import to work right? Is there a way I can test my code without having Excel installed?

Comment: If I'm understanding your reference to "Excel Application Object" correctly, then the answer to your last question is no.  But it would be a lot more clear if you would show at least a line or two of your code.

Comment: Hi Richard, thanks, it seems that there is really no other way hoping that there would be a way anyways about the first question maybe I would give some sample objects like "SymphonyApplication, SymphonySpreadsheet, Symphonysheet, CreateObject("Excel.Application"), ExcelObject.ActiveWorkbook and so on".. I was hoping that there would be a somewhat like help? maybe a site or even another nsf? Because right now I know how to use it but I don't really understand how it works and it's structure such us the hierarchy of the objects and it's method. Thanks a lot Richard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CreateObject("Excel.Application")...
```

is a COM call to create a reference to an ActiveX object. The help/reference to that ActiveX object can usually be found on the homepage of the objects vendor (in this case Microsoft). See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wss56bz7(v=vs.90).aspx

For StarOffice/OpenOffice/Symphony this is called ["Universal Network Objects" (UNO)](http://www.openoffice.org/udk/common/man/uno.html) and can be found here: http://www.openoffice.org/api/

Check out [John Heads](http://www.johndavidhead.com/jhead/johnhead.nsf/) blog and presentations for examples of both.. .

Comment: Hi Martin Leyler, Thanks a lot for the information. I am going to study more about it so that I could fully understand how it works in lotus notes. These links and guidance would help me a lot and I appreciate it that you answered my question. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Re your final question, as clarified in comments... For this to work:

```
CreateObject("Excel.Application")
```

Yes, you do have to have Excel installed on the system where the code executes.  There is no way around that.  However, this is not necessarily the only way to access Excel data.  If the spreadsheet is stored in the .xlsx format supported by newer versions of Excel, then it is really a zip file containing XML. It's by no means simple to work with, but theoretically you could use the documentation that can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd922181.aspx) to write whatever code you need using standard XML tools.

Comment: Hi Richard, I see though I clearly lack experience on using XML, so this would help me a lot to improve my skills and learn. I am going to study more about it. Thanks a lot for the information and link.